# putting jsonAsync code into seperate class... Android

Tags: android, json, class, asynchronous

I tried to make my code to be like this:
https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/src/com/bright/hub/background/WebServiceBackgroundActivity.java
This is how I call and send with the Async class, that seems to be fine.
If I put all the code in my MainActivity it just works, but I can't seem to get this code via a external class to work.

My MainActivity code: (parts which matter)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

private static final String url = "http://www.somesite.com/JSON.php";
public String post;
public ListView listView;
public String jsonResult;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
initializeDialog();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
accessWebService();
}
private void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask jsonTask = new JsonReadTask();
    jsonTask.execute(new String[] { url, post },this);
}

private void initializeDialog() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "LoadingData. Wait...", true);
    dialog.show();
    }   

    public void ListDrawer() {
    List<Map<String, String>> galleryList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    try {

   JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
   JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("galleries");

   for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

    String loc = jsonChildNode.optString("loc");
    String foto = jsonChildNode.optString("foto");
    String outPut = "http://www.somesite.com/images/" + loc + foto;
    galleryList.add(createGallery("galleries", outPut));
   }
  } catch (JSONException e) {
  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
     //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

}
```

But on the Async class:
https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/src/com/bright/hub/background/WebServiceAsyncTask.java
^I get these kinds of errors: "java.lang.String[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String"
So where this happens: "String serviceUrl = (String) params[0];" is where I have problems..?
It's in the "doInBackground" at least: "An error occured while executing doInBackground()"

My Async class code: (parts which matter)

```
    public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String> {
    MainActivity callerActivity;
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Object... params) {

    callerActivity = (MainActivity) params[1];
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String theurl = (String) params[0]; //urlJSON

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(theurl);
    try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    String thepost = (String) params[1]; //tablename
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("getgallery", "thepost"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        callerActivity.jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
    }

    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

The apps crashes on boot giving a Dialog it crashed.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit
My logcat: http://pastebin.com/XZaNZTTg

Comment: Ok, this is my log cat: http://pastebin.com/XZaNZTTg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two significant lines in the crash log:

```
10-13 11:49:43.881: E/AndroidRuntime(7289): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String
10-13 11:49:43.881: E/AndroidRuntime(7289):     at com.example.providenceartapp.JsonReadTask.doInBackground(JsonReadTask.java:31)
```

Somewhere you're trying to use a string array as a single string, it would look as if it's here

```
String theurl = (String) params[0]; //urlJSON;
```

`params[0]` is an array.

Comment: jsonTask.execute(new String[] { url, post },this); < This is how I send my strings to the Async class, the params[] is just getting a string from a string array. Any way to convert it so it would work? Or a bypass?

Comment: You're passing a string array and an activity, so `params[0]` is a string array. If you want to get the url you have to do `String theurl = params[0][0]`

Comment: When I do that I get: "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object"

Comment: That's because the params Object is an Object array. What do you get if you do `String [] parameters = (String []) params[0]` and then `String theurl = parameters[0]`?

Comment: Nice! That fixed the error. :) Just one more thing, when I try to do the same for my Table String... I get this error: http://pastebin.com/F1f8Cdu8 (code included)

Comment: Well, by doing: "callerActivity.post" I can just read it from my MainActivity. I don't think there are any problems with that I guess.. But hey it works! :) Thanks for your help Joe!